# How to use ResourceBundle

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, internationalization, resourcebundle

I'm trying to grasp internalization of java applications as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/list.html). I can't though. I have created a class that extends `ListResourceBundle` like stated and tried to retrieve the keys. I keep getting an exception though. If you check out the tutorial, it says to use ***.class*** files. This can't be right, can it?

**[PROJECT TREE]**

[image]

**[Source code]**

Here are the two classes I'm using, just one of the MainWindow_xx_XX.java files since they're basically the same.
First the ListResourceBundle:

```
public class MainWindow_en_US extends ListResourceBundle {

    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return contents;
    }
    private Object[][] contents = {
        {"fileLabel", "File"},
        {"newSessionLabel", "New session..."},
        {"openSessionLabel", "Open session..."},
        {"saveLabel", "Save"},
        {"exitLabel", "Exit"},
        {"editLabel", "Edit"},
        {"toolsLabel", "Tools"},
        {"helpLabel", "Help"}
    };
}
```

And now the method I use to load it:

```
    private static final int DEFAULT_LOCALE = 0;
    private ResourceBundle bundle;
    public static Locale locale;
    public static final Locale[] supportedLocales = {
        new Locale("en", "US"),
        new Locale("es", "ES")
    };

public MainWindow() {
    for (Locale i : supportedLocales) {
        if (i.getLanguage().equals(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage())) {
            locale = i;
            break;
        } else {
            locale = supportedLocales[DEFAULT_LOCALE];
        }
    }
    bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MainWindow", locale); //EXCEPTION POINTS HERE!!!
    initComponents();
}
```

I keep getting the following exception. I know I can do it through property files but it bugs me beyond reason the fact that I can't get Oracle's extremely simple tutorial to work.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name MainWindow, locale es_ES
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:796)
    at -.-.-.-.-.<init>(MainWindow.java:37)
    at -.-.-.-.MainWindow$2.run(MainWindow.java:145)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:671)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to use fully qualified base name:

```
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("pkg.subpkg.resources.MainWindow", locale);
```

Comment: This helped me along with specifying properly the `pkg.subpkg.resources.MainWindow` in the `msgfmt` command. i.e. The command was `msgfmt --java2 -d source/folder/root/ -r pkg.subpkg.resources.MainWindow my/po/file.po`

Answer (score 3):

You can't name a file `MainWindow_es_ES`. To solve your problem rename your file to `MainWindow es`.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es");
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("yourPackageName.MainWindow", locale);   
System.out.print(rb.getObject("YourKey"));
```